# Navigate to home screen if token is stored react-native o.w. login screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, stack-navigator

It's been couple of days I am stuck at a point where as a beginner I am not sure how to take it ahead.
In my `routes/main.js`, I have this stack navigator:

```
export const createRootNavigator = (loggedIn = false) => {
    return StackNavigator(
        {
            LoggedIn: {
                screen: LoggedIn
            },
            LoggedOut: {
                screen: LoggedOut
            }
        },
        {
            headerMode: loggedIn ? '' : 'none',
            mode: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'modal' : 'card',
            initialRouteName: loggedIn ? "LoggedIn" : "LoggedOut"
        }
    );
  }
```

**App.js**

```
import RootNavigation from './root';

const  App = () => ( {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store = {store} >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <RootNavigation/>
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
})
```

**root.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import { createRootNavigator} from './src/routes/main';

let RootNavigation = createRootNavigator(true);

export default class Root extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
            < RootNavigation / >
        );
    }
}
```

In **root.js** `let RootNavigation = createRootNavigator(true);` currently `true` is being passed, however it may be `true or false` which I supposed to get using `AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken');`

So I achieve something like this in my **root.js**

**Note:** Below code is incorrect but it explains what I want.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import { createRootNavigator} from './src/routes/main';

// Not sure about the code placement of this part.
let RootNavigation;
let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken');
if(token) {
    RootNavigation = createRootNavigator(true);
}else {
    RootNavigation = createRootNavigator(false);
}

export default class Root extends Component {

    render() {
        return ( 
            < RootNavigation / >
        );
    }
}
```

How can achieve this functionality? 
I am using `react-redux` and `react-thunk` in my project.
Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rendering different RootNavigations based on whether the user is logged in or not. You may look at initializing your stack with a Splash Screen that checks if there is an authenticated user. Since you are using redux, a convenient place to store this information might be in your store.

Once your Splash Screen mounts and you've asynchronously identified if there is an active user or not, you can then push to the login screen or first authenticated screen.

Headers on screens that change based on whether a user if authenticated or not are best configured using the static navigationOptions method, rather than configuring it on the stack.

Hope that helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Sounds good, if I have a splash screen which not the case here.

Comment: The approach I described does not require a splash screen. Your first screen could be any screen that checks and responds to authentication. Using your original approach you might find this example helpful. 

https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/building-an-authentication-flow-with-react-navigation-fb5de2203b5c